# ImproperlyConfigured: The staticfiles view can only be used in debug mode or if the --insecure option of 'runserver' is used

Tags: django, selenium, django-nose

I'm getting:

> ImproperlyConfigured: The staticfiles view can only be used in debug
>   mode or if the --insecure option of 'runserver' is used

when I try to run my tests. I know I have to serve my static files but my question is, since LiveServerTestCase use 8081 by default, what would be the best approach to serve these files?.

Any additional information please let me know :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not enabling debug mode ?

Comment: Someone recommended me in the IRC channel that's a bad practice. I'm installing nginx + gunicorn to have a production-like environment

Comment: damn, i just run into the same issue